# Nullpointer returns when trying to create a file

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception

I have this code to save an float array to a file for future use. But when I call it with the order `saveArray("the x",x);`  where x is the float array I want to save, it returns Null to the file and not created.

```
public void saveArray(String filename, float[] array) {
         try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(array);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e); 
         }
      }

     public float[] loadArray(String filename) {
          try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            float[] saved_array = (float[])in.readObject();
            in.close();
            return saved_array;
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
          }
          return null;
      }
```

this is what return me when I try to Save

```
05-04 07:21:59.547: I/System.out(622): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /the x: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
05-04 07:21:59.547: I/System.out(622): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /the x: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-04 07:21:59.557: I/System.out(622): null
```

EDIT2: I found a solution, but I want more help!

I left saveArray as before, and I create a dir and a file earlier.

```
final File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/works");
dir.mkdirs(); 
final File file = new File(dir, "the_x.txt");
saveArray(file.getPath()+file.getName(),x);
```

And seems to be saved. Now, I try to load it on another array, but the new array "a" never change values. Where you think is the mistake? Look above for my loadArray function.
I try these:

```
a = loadArray(file.getPath()+file.getName());
a = loadArray(file.getName());
a = loadArray(file.getPath());
a = loadArray("the_x.txt");
```

Comment: have added write permission in manifest?

Comment: No I didn't. It is needed?

Comment: yes. you need the permission

Comment: can you post the path of your file?

Comment: What did you mean? I didn't create it in any other position. What I write before, is what I use for the file

Comment: what's your filename?

Comment: I didn't create any file anywhere. The only String I "push" like a parameter is in saveArray("the x",x);

Answer (score 0):

If you are writting the file in sd card then you need following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Hence your `filanem` should be soething like `"/sdcard/yourfile.txt"`

you can use another thing

use

```
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
                context.openFileOutput(
                        filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

Comment: What did you mean? I didn't create it in any other position. What I write before, is what I use for the file

Comment: I just want to see the filename string.. want to see if you use any internal file

Comment: It doesn't let me to write "\sdcard\yourfile.txt". Maybe "/sdcard/yourfile.txt"?

Comment: now it change it and it appears message for permission
05-04 08:11:50.267: I/System.out(949): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/thex.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
I put what you write for permissions

Comment: if I remove /sdcard, I get the message 05-04 08:15:53.889: I/System.out(996): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /thex.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: what to put in context? A new null variable? And after, do that I post on edit up?

Comment: not not nulll variable :S.. use the context of activity or applciaation context

Comment: I found a solution, but I want more help, with load function! Please see my edited initial post